# Ideavim - how can I add digraphs

Tags: ideavim, digraphs

In Vim, i add digraphs by putting a line such as the following into my ~/.vimrc file to create a digraph for "ſ" (a long-s character):

---

:digr ls 383

---

However, adding such a line to my ~/.ideavimrc file has no effect. The default digraph set is in effect, but I cannot find a way to add to it.

Similarly, from within ideavim, the command

---

:digr ls 383

---

(for instance) doesn't work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

I just saw your post and tried just the standard ctrl-K prefix, for instance ctrl-K J A gives Я or ctrl-K a * α

you can see the full list of vim digraphs in vim with `:di` or [here](https://vimhelp.org/digraph.txt.html)

Comment: You didn't read the question.

Comment: You are right, my apologies.